# WCF service Post request gives error if calling from browser like "Method not allowed."

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-data-services

i have created WCF POST method. when i call it from browser by passing parameter in querystring it gives me error like

> Method not allowed. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service

my code is in interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    //[OperationContract]
    //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/UpdateDeviceStatus?FaultStatus={FaultStatus}&MacAddress={MacAddress}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    //string UpdateDeviceStatus(string FaultStatus, string MacAddress);


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/UpdateDeviceStatus?FaultStatus={FaultStatus}&MacAddress={MacAddress}")]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    string UpdateDeviceStatus(string FaultStatus, string MacAddress);
}
```

And in Service.svc

```
public string UpdateDeviceStatus(string FaultStatus, string MacAddress)
{
    try
    {
       // here my operation
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Failed to update";
    }
}
```

URL that i am calling from browser is

```
http://localhost:2121/WcfService/Service.svc/UpdateDeviceStatus?FaultStatus={1}&MacAddress={20:10:00:20:10:00}
```

NOTE: if i use webGet method then it works but for POST method it is not working can any one please give me solution for this?

Comment: a browser cannot send `POST` requests.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a resource by typing in the address in your browser, the request is done via GET.

That's why your service complains: the request is done via GET, which isn't allowed because you defined to allow only POST-requests (`[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",`).

To be able to do other requests than only GETs, I'd recommend you to use tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) which allows you to compose any kind of http request.

The hint you got via the error message is very valuable, too: take a look at your service help page. The required format and the generated output is shown there. For enabling the service help page, take a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee230442(v=VS.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try like -

```
public class CompositeType
{
    public string FaultStatus { get; set; }
    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
}


[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "post")]
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
```

[image]

Use `Fiddler` or similar tools to check it works.

Also, you could modify your `config` to enable help on your service -

```
 <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="e">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

This helps you with the allowed operations, their possible request and response body formats etc by navigating to *yoururl/service.svc/help*

Answer (score 0):

Use debugging tools(developer options)  of your browser (for Firefox it is F12 Key). 
In the network tab, you will find that browser is sending a get request to the server while server is expecting  a POST. 
hence the error.